# iOS push notifications does not play sound and does not show badge alert [in Objective C]

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I was using the demo instructions provided here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/

here is the main code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    UIUserNotificationType types = (UIUserNotificationType) (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |                                                               
UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert);


    UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings =
    [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];

    return YES;
}

-(void)MessageBox:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)messageText
{
   // OLD way of sending push notifications:

   // UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:messageText delegate:self
   //                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
   // [alert show];


    UIAlertController* alert=   [UIAlertController
                                  alertControllerWithTitle:title
                                  message:messageText
                                 preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];


    UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                          handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {}];

    [alert addAction:defaultAction];
    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

I get notifications to appear, however there is not sound and badge update.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you actually sending a remote notification to APNS on your server or are you using a local notification in your app?  It appears that all you are doing is presenting an alert dialog which makes sense that you have no badge and sound.

Comment: Thanks for both feedbacks. I wasn't clear completely. I was setting up badge and sound in code. Then sending a 3rd party payload. my payload message was incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you included the badge and sound parameters in your JSON payload?

**EXAMPLE**

```
{"aps":{"alert":"Example notification title","badge":1,"sound":"default"}}
```

I'd read up on the [Apple Push Notification Payload Documents](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH107-SW1) to familiarise yourself.

Comment: Oh wow. Everything works now. My original message was something like ... {"aps":{"alert":"Example notification title"}}. I didn't think sound and badge were done through payload. I thought that they had to be set up in App delegate, and then the phone would infer or something. Woops!

Comment: @js_55 Glad its working now, I'd recommend reading the APN docs on JSON payloads to familiarise yourself with everything because they can be quite tricky at first. Here is the link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH107-SW1